# How to create a C header file using Javah?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, javah

I am using android ndk, and for that I am trying to create a c header file using the javah tool. How to use and where to use this tool? I am unable to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javah should be in the bin folder of your JDK

Something like this:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\bin

For simplicities sake take the path name folder from the bin directory in your Android project and place it in the above directory.

Then use the command prompt

> javah -jni com.pathname.ClassName

And the header file will be created in the JDK bin folder

Comment: I am working on ubuntu , and i am facing the same problem , i am working on NDK in eclipse .Can you help me create header file , the path are as follows:
javah : /usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/javah
android-sdk: /home/rana/android-sdk-mac-x86
ndk: /home/rana/Download/android-ndk-r9
AndroidJNI (sample project) : /home/rana/workspace/AndroidJni